# Psensors/Watch Sensors Repeatedly Freezes 15.04

Tags: 15.04, sensors

When using the psensors application or watch sensors in the command line, my system hangs repeatedly, during which the mouse and keyboard are unresponsive. Before upgrading to 15.04, I was able to watch sensors on 14.04 without issue. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Does `xsensors` work?

Comment: xsensors freezes the system as well

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I run a Dell XPS1640 using ubuntu 15.04.
My problem was resolved by removing the i8k module.

You can try the following:

1. Check if the module is loaded by typing the following in  a terminal

`lsmod | grep i8k`

2. To unload the module, type the following in a terminal

`sudo rmmod i8k`

3. Run sensors to test if it worked.